# replay of the finished message through foreach

Tags: ros, ros2, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a msg message containing 45 variables, and I’m actually able to fill in the message variables through a loop or should I write each variable manually? I use ros2, I write on C++, assembly ament_cmake

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314919/replay-of-the-finished-message-through-foreach/) by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-02-07**:
This question doesn't make much sense? What do these 45 variables represent?

**Comment by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on 2019-02-07**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd
float32 voltage
float32 charge_level
float32 block_n_voltage
float32 block_n_amperage
float32 akb_voltage
float32 akb_amperage
float32 temperature_akb400v
bool availability_of_coolant_duct_akb400v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's not a generic way to loop over differently named elements. You will need to specifically address them individually.

If you want to loop across elements you can store them in an array. But as these elements appear to be quite specific and different. Aka they're not representing multiple instances of a type the separate variables makes more sense. The temperature and amperage are not interchangeable. And some elements are even of different types which makes iterating even less likely. If you have those 45 things to assign specifically you're going to need to actually assign them individually. This way the compiler will know exactly what you want to do and anyone reading the code will also know what you're doing. Trying to save lines of code to avoid this sort of thing is likely not worth it. If you're assigning into it from a similar data struct in several different places a helper function is the best way to do this.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0